# Alternatives to SharePoint 2013 deprecated workflow actions

Tags: sharepoint

As we see there is no STOP Workflow action in SharePoint 2013 Designer workflows is there any workaround to achieve the same using SPD 2013.I my case I can't use SPD 2010 Workflows also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Go to" action instead:
http://prasadtechtactics.blogspot.com/2012/07/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflows-part.html

Section 7 of below cource on MVA demonstrates usage of such action as well:
http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/developing-microsoft-sharepoint-server-2013-core-solutions-jump-start